# WPF C# edit string in resource file

Tags: c#, wpf

will i know how to edit string in normal C#  apps

```
Properties.Settings.Default.String1 = "whatever";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

but this not seems to be working in wpf i get the string like this in wpf apps

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(Resources));
string string1 = rm.GetString("string_key");
```

How to update string resource in WPF C#  ?

> Solution: My bad i was doing to much java lately and i mixed resources
>   with settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

Updating the Resource:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.String1 = "whatever";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Reading the Resource:

```
string a String = Properties.Settings.Default.String1;
```